# Survey questions need to show and hide based on parent answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this https://jsfiddle.net/jorden15/9yz45bz8/ to show you what is going on. Basically I have a Survey builder that creates the html for this survey and the functionality I'm working on is hiding and showing child questions based on the answer of the parent.

For example if you select yes on the first question the child question should pull up which it does. My problem is that there are four questions deep and if I select no at any point it shows the last question. The last question should trigger on no but only as a result of its parent and nothing else.

I'm thinking that the issue has something to do with my show variable. As a radio button will be undefined but I'm not sure what to do.

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('change', '.parent_question select, .parent_question input', function(){
    var child_input = $('[name="' + $(this).data('child-name') + '"]');
    var child_question = child_input.closest('.survey_answers');
    var trigger_on = $(this).data('trigger-on');
    var show = $(this)[0].selectedIndex == undefined ? ($(this).closest('.survey_answers').find('input').index($(this)) + 1) == trigger_on : $(this)[0].selectedIndex == trigger_on;
    console.log(show);
    if (show) {
      child_question.show();
    } else {
      child_question.hide();
      if (child_input.val() != '' || child_input.is(':checked')) {
        child_input.val('');
        child_input.attr('checked', false);
        child_input.trigger('change');
      }
  }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue. The problem was I was trying to hide questions after showing them if the answers changed but I was just doing it backwards and it didn't like that.

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('change', '.parent_question select, .parent_question input', function(){
    var child_input = $('[name="' + $(this).data('child-name') + '"]');
    var child_question = child_input.closest('.survey_answers');
    var trigger_on = $(this).data('trigger-on');
    var show = $(this)[0].selectedIndex == undefined ? ($(this).closest('.survey_answers').find('input').index($(this)) + 1) == trigger_on : $(this)[0].selectedIndex == trigger_on;
    console.log(show);
    if (show && (child_input.val() != '' || child_input.is(':checked'))) {
      child_question.show();
    } else {
      child_question.hide();
      child_input.val('');
      child_input.attr('checked', false);
      child_input.trigger('change');
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Jorden, would you accept your answer? To do so, click the tick mark to the left, so that it is marked as resolved. We encourage self-answers here. Thanks!